# Due to IPython and Windows limitation, python multiprocessing isn't available now. So `number_workers` is changed to 0 to avoid getting stuck

Tags: multiprocessing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOAlv.png)

```
#id first_training
#caption Results from the first training
# CLICK ME
from fastai.vision.all import *
path = untar_data(URLs.PETS)/'images'

def is_cat(x): return x[0].isupper()
dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_name_func(
    path, get_image_files(path), valid_pct=0.2, seed=42,
    label_func=is_cat, item_tfms=Resize(224))

learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fine_tune(1)
```

Due to IPython and Windows limitation, python multiprocessing isn't available now.
So `number_workers` is changed to 0 to avoid getting stuck

Hi, i am studying with Fastai book and i run this code without colab or paperspace.

But as not what i expected, it is taking so long time (my computer is workstation)

but i am wondering if i clear that error

maybe increasing 'number_workers', it would be much faster than before.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Answer (score -1):

fastai directly using Jupyter notebook in Win10 will occur this limit.It can go on if u wait.But it would operate slowly and it would influence the performence of the GPU.There is no mistakes when it runs in macOS or Linux, which proves the Window is still not suitable to do the deeplearning work to a extent.I wish it would be helpful to you.